# Machine learning feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have 40 Independent variables in dataframe.
Out of these 40 IV's 6 IV's are as follows,

| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X5 | X6 | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 21 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 19 |

As seen in above table, target variable value is a sum of values of 6 IV's (X1 to X6) i.e., 1+2+3+4+5+6=21

My question is should I consider these IV's for building a regression models along with other features.

Will it affect my model performance if i use them even if there is less correlation between these IV's and Target(less than 0.5) ?

What should be correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

From a purely pragmatic perspective:

If you have 6 variables, the sum of which are exactly your target variable, then you have no need to build a predictive model. You can use deterministic methods to get the answer which you need, without bias or potential error, which all predictive models carry.

If you will have only a subset of these values (the same ones each time) available in the future, and other correlated variables it might be worth building a predictive model. But you should only use the variables that you will have, and then only if they are in someway individually correlated with your target and you cannot compute the outcome directly.

Comment: so i have a problem in hand to build a predictive model only. I have 16 power absorption columns & my target is simply a sum of these 16 power absorption values (Total_power). 

I want to know will it be a right or wrong to use these 16 features along with other features to predict my target?

Comment: Will you have those values when you run the prediction in the future? The thing about using data from the same instant to predict something happening in that instant. From a real world perspective, that is not a useful model, even if it is predictive because the event you a trying to predict will be already known. Is there a specific reason not to computationally or model success-wise, no (except that a deterministic model is more accurate).

I would build the model without the six and see how good it is.

Comment: Thanks that answered my question.